# Ionic-5, Reactive Form, refresh the page on submit

Tags: ionic-framework

I have a simple reactive form :

```
<ion-content>
  <form [formGroup]="contactForm" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>MM DD YY</ion-label>
    <ion-datetime displayFormat="MM DD YY" placeholder="Select Date" [min]="minDate" (ionChange)="getScheduleDate($event)" formControlName="scheduleDate" name="scheduleDate"></ion-datetime>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-button  color="primary"  type="submit">Submit</ion-button>
</form>    
</ion-content>
```

On click of Submit, it refresh the page. Anyone suggestion pls for this. I don't want click event in button.

Comment: Please clarify your question. Are you saying that your current code causes the page to refresh on submit, and you don't want it to do that?

Comment: yes, on submit click, page should not refresh.

Comment: I can't reproduce that. Seems to be working fine. Can you do a stackblitz?

Answer (score -1):

Remove type="submit" from the ion-button. Then the click event will not fire.

Comment: Not a solution, bro,